# Fisher information for predictions

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models, model, fisher-information

Assume I have a model (linear regression, neural network, etc) in the form $g(\theta)$ and I assume that my data is generated according to  $f(x; g(\theta))$ (eg $f$ is the pdf of a normal Gaussian random variable and I am parametrizing the mean $g(\theta)$ with my model).

I then optimize my model by maximizing the log likelihood $\log f(g(\theta); x)$. In this example we can assume $\theta \in \mathbb R^n, g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$

I would like to get a confidence interval on the predictions of the model $g(\theta)$ using the fisher information.

However, I am a bit confused on how to go about that exactly:

If I compute the fisher information wrt to $g(\theta)$, which is what actually determines the pdf, I obtain an interesting statistics (how much information about each parameter of the pdf (eg the mean) is in the data) but this *does not* depend on the model, so I cannot use it as a measure of how confident we are in a specific prediction $g(\theta)$

I can compute the fisher information wrt to $\theta$, the parameters of the model, but then I have confidence intervals on the parameters, not on the predictions, and I care about the confidence intervals on the prediction $g(\theta)$. I could at that point vary the parameters across a specified confidence interval (e.g. $\pm 1.96 \cdot \text {fisher information}$) and see what happens to $g(\theta)$, but that would probably be inaccurate (probably does not guarantee a 95% confidence interval) and more than that, it's too expensive (exponential in $n$).

Can you clarify how I should proceed? Links to resources are appreciated!

Comment: Since you are using maximum likelihood, the MLE of $g(\theta)$ is $g(\hat\theta).$  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+likelihood+invariance.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment! I am not sure I understand it though; yes the MLE of $g(\theta)$ is $g(\hat \theta)$, but how does that help me find confidence intervals for $g(\theta)$?

Basically, how can I go from confidence intervals on the parameters $\theta$ (computed using fisher information) to confidence intervals on the predictions $g(\theta)$?

Comment: Because $g(\theta)$ is a parameter, you compute confidence intervals for it in the same way you would compute CIs for any parameter.

Comment: @whuber Uhm but $g(\theta)$ is a function of the model. So let's assume the $X$ is a 2d random variable with unknown mean. If I have $\mu_1, \mu_2$ as parameters of the model directly, I compute the MLE and confidence intervals as usual. 

But assume instead I want a model $g$ which predicts $\mu_1, \mu_2$, and that the model is really bad: $\hat \mu_1 = \hat \mu_2 = g(\theta)$ (where $\theta \in \mathbb R$). If I now compute the MLE wrt to $\theta$, I find that 
1. The confidence interval on $\hat \mu_i$ are not the same as before (they must be the equal for $i = 1, 2$), which [...]

Comment: [continued] ... which was not the case before. 2. given that the model is bad, I am expecting lower confidence (for some meaning of confidence) on the estimate of $\hat \mu_1 = \hat \mu_2 = g(\theta)$. Perhaps I am using incorrect terminology, but hopefully now it's clear what I mean? 

Thanks for your time, would really appreciate a pointer in the right direction!

Comment: "Function of the model" is one *definition* of a parameter.